# SCOPE_IDENTITY() return 1

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, scope-identity

I use this code in SQL Server 2012:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[test] ([t]) 
VALUES ('tyy');

SELECT [Id] 
FROM [dbo].[test] 
WHERE ([Id] = SCOPE_IDENTITY())
```

It returns the last inserted id and it worked well.

But the same code in vb.net 2017 and .net Framework 4.7.2 is not working - for every insert, it returns 1.

This is the code:

```
Dim id = TestTableAdapter.InsertQuery("nvnh")
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test] 
(
    [Id] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [t]  NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Comment: Are you certain that the previous insert is running in the same scope as your second insert in the VB.net code?

Comment: You can simply use _SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()_ instead of your select...from...where

Comment: What is `TestTableAdapter.InsertQuery`? Are you sure it's returning the resulset and not maybe the number of rows affected?

Comment: thanks for replay,yes i am sure in save scope,i used SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()  also worked in sql server but returned 1 in vb.net,TestTableAdapter.InsertQuery is query have the same code inside datatable inside dataset designer

Comment: You would have to declare an object of SqlTransaction type and call myConnection.BeginTransaction()   do your work  and then call myTrans.Commit();      then close the myConnection.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

thanks for all.
i finally found the solution.

i use already any from above solutions,

but the query `eqcutemode` is `NonQuery` ,so it give me the count of inserted rows
i changed it to `Scalar`

Comment: You should have let other people answer first. I did ask you this in my comment a while ago but you didn't check it.

Comment: thanks for you,i see it and your comment plus another search in google,and i catch it.